# How can I Join Two Query

Tags: sql-server

How can I join two queries that are bellow:

```
Required output query: 
Query#1_Col_1, Query#1_Col_2, 
Query#1_Col3, Query#2_Col_1,
Query#2_Col_2, Query#2_Col_3
```

Query#01

```
 ;With RnkItems As
    (
SELECT    
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.AppID, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GRelationWithCustomer, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GFahterSpoueName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GMotherName, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GDesig, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine1, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine2, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine3, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne1, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne2, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne3, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPrePhone, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GResPhone, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GMobile, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GResStatus, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPermanentAddress1, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPermanentAddress2, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GID, 
ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.AppID Order By GID, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GName) As Rnk
FROM dbo.TblGuarantorInfo)

SELECT AppID 
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GName End ) As G1_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G1_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G1_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GMotherName end ) AS G1_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessName end ) AS G1_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GDesig end ) AS G1_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G1_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G1_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G1_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G1_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G1_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G1_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPrePhone end ) AS G1_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GResPhone end ) AS G1_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GMobile end ) AS G1_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GResStatus end ) AS G1_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G1_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G1_perAddress2

,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GName End ) As G1_Name2
,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G2_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G2_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GMotherName end ) AS G2_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessName end ) AS G2_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GDesig end ) AS G2_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G2_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G2_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G2_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G2_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G2_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G2_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPrePhone end ) AS G2_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GResPhone end ) AS G2_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GMobile end ) AS G2_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GResStatus end ) AS G2_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G2_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G2_perAddress2

,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GName End ) As G3_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G3_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G3_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GMotherName end ) AS G3_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessName end ) AS G3_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GDesig end ) AS G3_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G3_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G3_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G3_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G3_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G3_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G3_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPrePhone end ) AS G3_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GResPhone end ) AS G3_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GMobile end ) AS G3_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GResStatus end ) AS G3_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G3_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G3_perAddress2
,Min( Case When Rnk=4 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G4_Relation

,MIN (Case When Rnk=4 Then GName End ) As G4_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=4 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G4_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GMotherName end ) AS G4_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessName end ) AS G4_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GDesig end ) AS G4_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G4_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G4_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G4_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G4_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G4_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G4_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPrePhone end ) AS G4_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GResPhone end ) AS G4_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GMobile end ) AS G4_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GResStatus end ) AS G4_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G4_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G4_perAddress2

From RnkItems 
Group By AppID
```

Query#02

```
select dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID , dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppAsignTo, 
    dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppName, dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanType, dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanStatus, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClFatherName, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClMotherName, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClDOB, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPrePhone, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreMobile, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClResidentStatus, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine1, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine2, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine3, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine4, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine1, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine2, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine3, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine4, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfOccupation, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfCompanyName, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfDesig, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine1, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine2, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine3, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine4
    FROM dbo.TblMasterInfo INNER JOIN
    dbo.TblClientInfo ON dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID = dbo.TblClientInfo.AppID INNER JOIN
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo ON dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID = dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.APPID 
    WHERE (dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanType = 'Auto Loan') AND (dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanStatus = 'Disbursed')
```

Comment: that's too much.. you should provide initial and desired output

Comment: What is the relation between the two queries? Can you please simplify the queries to the main problem? It is two hard for any one to understand all this code.

Comment: dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID and dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.AppID are the relation for these two table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are long queries, I'm not going to write it all in here directly, but you can use that pattern to link to inner queries:

```
select x.column1, x.column2, y.column3, y.column4
from
(
   -- your whole query 1
) x
inner join
(
   -- your whole query 2
) y
on x.id = y.id
```

**EDIT**

Hope this works, those queries are too big to check:

```
;With RnkItems As
    (
SELECT    
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.AppID, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GRelationWithCustomer, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GFahterSpoueName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GMotherName, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessName, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GDesig, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine1, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine2, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GBusinessAddressLine3, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne1, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne2, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.ResidenceAddressLIne3, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPrePhone, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GResPhone, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GMobile, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GResStatus, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPermanentAddress1, 
dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GPermanentAddress2, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GID, 
ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.AppID Order By GID, dbo.TblGuarantorInfo.GName) As Rnk
FROM dbo.TblGuarantorInfo)

SELECT AppID 
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GName End ) As G1_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G1_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=1 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G1_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GMotherName end ) AS G1_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessName end ) AS G1_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GDesig end ) AS G1_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G1_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G1_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G1_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G1_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G1_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G1_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPrePhone end ) AS G1_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GResPhone end ) AS G1_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GMobile end ) AS G1_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GResStatus end ) AS G1_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G1_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=1 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G1_perAddress2

,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GName End ) As G1_Name2
,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G2_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=2 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G2_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GMotherName end ) AS G2_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessName end ) AS G2_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GDesig end ) AS G2_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G2_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G2_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G2_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G2_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G2_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G2_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPrePhone end ) AS G2_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GResPhone end ) AS G2_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GMobile end ) AS G2_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GResStatus end ) AS G2_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G2_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=2 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G2_perAddress2

,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GName End ) As G3_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G3_Relation
,MIN (Case When Rnk=3 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G3_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GMotherName end ) AS G3_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessName end ) AS G3_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GDesig end ) AS G3_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G3_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G3_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G3_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G3_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G3_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G3_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPrePhone end ) AS G3_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GResPhone end ) AS G3_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GMobile end ) AS G3_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GResStatus end ) AS G3_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G3_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=3 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G3_perAddress2
,Min( Case When Rnk=4 Then GRelationWithCustomer End ) As G4_Relation

,MIN (Case When Rnk=4 Then GName End ) As G4_Name
,MIN (Case When Rnk=4 Then GFahterSpoueName end ) As G4_FatherName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GMotherName end ) AS G4_MotherName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessName end ) AS G4_BusinessName
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GDesig end ) AS G4_Desig
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine1 end ) AS G4_BusLine1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine2 end ) AS G4_BusLine2
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GBusinessAddressLine3 end ) AS G4_BusLine3
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne1 end ) AS G4_Res1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne2 end ) AS G4_Res2
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then ResidenceAddressLIne3 end ) AS G4_Res3
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPrePhone end ) AS G4_PrePhone
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GResPhone end ) AS G4_ResPhone
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GMobile end ) AS G4_MobileNo
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GResStatus end ) AS G4_ResStatus
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPermanentAddress1 end ) AS G4_PerAddress1
,MIN (case when rnk=4 then GPermanentAddress2 end ) AS G4_perAddress2
into #temp
From RnkItems 
Group By AppID

select x.*, t.* from #temp t
inner join 
(select dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID , dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppAsignTo, 
    dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppName, dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanType, dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanStatus, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClFatherName, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClMotherName, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClDOB, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPrePhone, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreMobile, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClResidentStatus, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine1, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine2, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine3, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPreAddressLine4, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine1, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine2, 
    dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine3, dbo.TblClientInfo.ClPerAddressLine4, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfOccupation, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfCompanyName, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfDesig, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine1, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine2, dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine3, 
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.ProfAddressLine4
    FROM dbo.TblMasterInfo INNER JOIN
    dbo.TblClientInfo ON dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID = dbo.TblClientInfo.AppID INNER JOIN
    dbo.TblProfessionalInfo ON dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID = dbo.TblProfessionalInfo.APPID 
    WHERE (dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanType = 'Auto Loan') AND (dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppLoanStatus = 'Disbursed')) x
on x.AppID = t.AppID
```

Comment: i use like you:  Select q1.*, q2.*
  
  From 
  ( query#1 Statement ) q1

inner join

(  query#2 Statement   ) q2
 on q1.AppID = q2.AppID 
  but doesn't work

Comment: You mean gives you an syntax error or doesn't return the right data?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your first query uses CTE. You need to select the results of this query into a temp table and use that in the subquery.

Comment: I can't use temp table. If you don't mind please complete my required as I am not expert in programming.

Comment: Please check that. You need to put proper columns into last select (select x.*, t.*) as I wasn't sure which columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two tables use the inner join

For Eample
select e.coloumn1,e.coloumn2,l.coloumn3 from employee e inner join leavedetails l on e.coloumn1=l.coloumn3

if you want to use where condition

select e.coloumn1,e.coloumn2,l.coloumn3 from employee e inner join leavedetails l on e.coloumn1=l.coloumn3 where e.coloumn1='xxxx'